# Select latest record if column has 2 of the same

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have table

```
**id name status date**

1 john 2 01.01.2010
2 mike 5 04.01.2010
3 john 2 06.01.2010
4 sam  1 08.01.2010
```

john has status 2 twice and i need to select john,mike from this table where status = 2 but i need to show latest record.
I cannot use `order by` i use it already for something else.

Comment: You have to use `order by` for what you want. Luckily you can use `order by` for more than 1 column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order by` for multiple criteria like this:

```
ORDER BY date desc, status desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a correlated subquery such as this:

```
select * 
from table t1
where t1.date = ( select max( t2.date )
                  from table t2
                  where t1.name = t2.name
                  and t1.status = t2.status )
```

Answer (score 1):

The query would go much faster if you didn't need the ID field:

```
SELECT t.name, t.status, max(t.date) date
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.name, t.status
ORDER BY [whatever]
```

If you DID need id, AND the ID is guarenteed to be larger on the record with the newer date, you could just add `max(t.id) id` to the field list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE status = 2
AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table tmp WHERE tmp.name = t.name GROUP BY name)
```